# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client - Enable Response compression

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am developing a application which uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client for the push messages . I have a javascript client which speaks to the server. Since my application could be used in varying internet speeds, i want to keep the transport payload as minimum as possible.

For normal HTTP requests and responses i have enabled the compression by using

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddResponseCompression();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();
    }
}
```

But when i looked across internet to do the same with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client, i could not find any doc reference or any examples. So is it possible to enable compression for Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client ? If so how. Please help.

My environment

```
Dotnet core: 3.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize for low bandwidth you could use MessagePack instead of Json for the payload serialization.

> MessagePack is a fast and compact binary serialization format. It's
> useful when performance and bandwidth are a concern because it creates
> smaller messages compared to JSON. The binary messages are unreadable
> when looking at network traces and logs unless the bytes are passed
> through a MessagePack parser. SignalR has built-in support for the
> MessagePack format, and provides APIs for the client and server to
> use.

(taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-3.1#what-is-messagepack-1)).

To make use of message pack you have to activate it on the server like this:

```
services.AddSignalR()
    .AddJsonProtocol(options => {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null
    });
```

On the client you have to install the appropriate npm package

```
npm install @microsoft/signalr-protocol-msgpack
```

and then initialize your connection appropriately:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chathub")
    .withHubProtocol(new signalR.protocols.msgpack.MessagePackHubProtocol())
    .build();
```

For more details see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#jsonmessagepack-serialization-options-1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-messagepack-on-the-client-1

Comment: so there is no inbuilt compression available ?

Comment: not at the moment but you could either achieve similar results with MessagePack or roll your own compression. nevertheless i would suggest measuring if your scenario would benefit of compression at all. this is just the case if your messages are large enough. if you send lots of small messages separately, compression could even increase the size of your messages.

Comment: Not having compression is a huge problem for some cases... For me it's the difference between 3-10MB responses vs 150-300KB responses for some endpoints....